# How to determine if insertions have been completed in ibatis?

Tags: java, sql, ibatis, ibatis.net

```
@Insert("insert into TABLE(c1, c2, c3) " +
        "values ( #{col1}, #{col2}, #{col3})")
Boolean save(Integer x, Integer y);
```

The returning Boolean would be True or False, determining if everything has been inserted properly

Comment: iBatis or MyBatis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyway, you cannot do that. You need to use an `int` (or `Integer`) and compare it to `0`.
If `result == 0,` then no rows have been inserted.

```
@Insert("insert into TABLE(c1, c2, c3) values (#{col1}, #{col2}, #{col3})")
int save(final Integer x, final Integer y);
```

Using `MyBatis`, you could have defined a custom `ResultHandler<T>`